# PERN STACK - Connect to Database dynamically

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql, express

I'm working on project in PERN STACK and I need to connect 2 different databases simultaneously..
I created 1 pool for the source DB then when user login to the system I take the credentials and connect him to another DB.

The 1st DB is global for all users
the 2nd DB is per customer dynamically

```
require("dotenv").config()

const { Pool } = require('pg')

const vam = new Pool({
  user: process.env.db_user,
  host: process.env.db_host,
  database: 'vam',
  password: process.env.db_password,
  port: process.env.db_port,
})

const anotherDB = new Pool({
  user: process.env.db_user,
  host: process.env.db_host,
  database: 'Here I need to bring the data from the user..',
  password: process.env.db_password,
  port: process.env.db_port,
})

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

I've main file for server.js and another file for manage the connection to PostgreSQL.

Thank you for your time :)